# About Window onload, ondomready etc

Tags: javascript, jsf, iframe

From [Geek Daily](http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/07/27/javascript-windowonload-is-bad-mkay/) :

> The onload event does not fire until every last piece of the page is loaded.

Now I have a inframe in my jsf application and I can not replace by any means, this iframe with any other jsf component. I am trying to set the scroll position of the scrollbar resides in that iframe to a particular coordinate when the iframe is loaded. I have tried this:

```
    window.onLoad(onLoad);

    function onLoad() {
        var frames = window.parent.frames;
        var iframe = frames['frameR'];
        iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 200);
    }
```

But it's not working. I placed an `alert(iframe)` after `var iframe = frames['frameR'];` and it was displaying a message `[object Window]` but `iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 200);` is not working at all.

Either I am doing something wrong or as all the jsf components are not rendered in the iframe, the iframe's scroll position can be set then.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Is `onLoad` is the last event before render of all the components?

Comment: Has the iframe's content finished loading by the time your script runs?

Comment: @rkaregaran is there any way to know whether or not the contents are finished loading? I am saw when the alert message popped up, in the back of that alert only the title of the iframe was visible.

Comment: I don't know if theres a way to identify that an iframe's unload has completed. Maybe you can just try to add some wait before firing your scroll-to script?

Comment: Most browsers will render as they go, they like to show users something as soon as possible as it makes them look fast. The load event fires after all content is displayed, which is why it's less than optimal if you are waiting for it before doing things in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `window.onload`, note capitalisation.

It is best to set the frame's onload listener from the code going into the iframe. It can be done from the parent document, but if you wait for the main document's load event to make sure the iFrame exists, the iframe's load may have already fired.

You can also use a script element immediately below the iFrame to set it's onload property:

```
<iframe id="frameR" src="..."></iframe>

<script>
  var el = document.getElementById('frameR');
  if (el) el.onload = doStuff;
</script>
```